# How Do I Append Multiple Items To A List?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How can I append numerous items to a list?

I want to avoid doing this:

```
empty_list = []

empty_list.append('How')
empty_list.append('are')
empty_list.append('you')
```

Comment: `empty_list = ['How', 'are', 'you']`? Use `list.extend`? Also note that `empty_list` is a bad name once it isn't!

Comment: by extending it with `empty_list.extend([<items>])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.extend`:

```
empty_list = []
empty_list.extend(['How', 'are', 'you'])
```